# kdb+ : concatenate table elements into a third column

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have this:

```
a     b     c
"aa"  "bb"  "cc"
"aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
```

I want to end up with -,|,/,\ in between or any other third string:

```
a     b     c     ab
"aa"  "bb"  "cc"  "aa-bb"
"aaa" "bbb" "ccc" ""aaa-bbb"
```

for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q)d:flip `a`b`c!flip 2 3#'\:"abc"
q)select ab:sv'["-";flip (a;b)] from d
ab
---------
"aa-bb"
"aaa-bbb"
q)select  "-"0:(a;b) from d
b
---------
"aa-bb"
"aaa-bbb"
```

Comment: Thank you Sean. This does work, BUT there must be a simpler way. List vs. List to spit out a third list. Anyone has any other ideas?

Comment: You are going to have to do something with a, and do something with b, to get "ab". The only complexity I added was to make your example tabular, but it looks like you have column headers anyway, so I suspect it's a table you are dealing with. Making it a table format will allow you to form other columns based on your reqs, e.g. "ac", but you will still need to manipulate a and c in some way to get ac.

Comment: Indeed this is what I was looking for, I just had to use "exec" instead of select because select would place the dict in the third column instead of the actual value, which "exec" does. Thanks Sean.